# How to add tooltip for the inner doughnut

Tags: chart.js

Can't work out how to add tooltip for the inner doughnut
Using chart.js 1.0.1, the fiddle has 2.7.2 library

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/216304/

```
tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
            var tooltipData  = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
    var tooltipData1 = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data1[tooltipItem.index];
    return tooltipLabel + ': £' + tooltipData + ', ' + tooltipData1 + '% ';
                    }
                  }
              }
          }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To future self:

added data1:[] after data[] in the dataset,

```
 data: [
{% for row in monthlyChart_avg_prev %}
"{{ row[6] }}",
{% endfor %}
],
data1: [
{% for row in monthlyChart_avg_prev %}
"{{ row[8] }}",
{% endfor %}
],
```

then in toolips:

```
 tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
            var tooltipData  = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
var tooltipData1 = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data1[tooltipItem.index];
return tooltipLabel + ': £' + tooltipData + ', ' + tooltipData1 + '% ';
                    }
                  }
              }
```

found on [chartsjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/doughnut.html)